# Change Newline code to non-italic or non-bold in Google Docs with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script, I'd like to change newline codes of my Google Documents to non italic or non bold with the following code.

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(DOCUMENT_ID);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // set new line code to non-bold and non-italic  =>  This is *NOT* working
  replaceBoldorItalic(body, '\n', 'bold', false);
  replaceBoldorItalic(body, '\n', 'italic', false);

  // set #(@) character to non-bold(non-italic)  =>  This is working
  replaceBoldorItalic(body, '#', 'bold', false);
  replaceBoldorItalic(body, '@', 'italic', false);
}

function getMatch(text, str) {
  if (str === '\n') {
    var match = new RegExp(text.match(/\n/g), 'gm');
    return match
  }
  var match = new RegExp(text.match(str), 'gm');
  return match
}

function replaceBoldorItalic(body, str, bold_or_italic, boolean) {
  var asText = body.asText();
  var text = asText.getText();
  
  var match = getMatch(text, str);
  var pos = 0;
  var posN = 0;
  while ((arr = match.exec(text)) !== null) {
    posN = text.indexOf(str, pos);
    if (posN !== -1) {
      if (bold_or_italic === 'bold') {
        asText.setBold(posN, posN + str.length - 1, boolean);
      } else if (bold_or_italic === 'italic') {
        asText.setItalic(posN, posN + str.length - 1, boolean);
      } else {
        console.log('bold_or_italic should be bold or italic')
      }
    }
    pos = match.lastIndex;
  }
}
```

But this does not work.
It works with normal characters like # and @ and strings but does not work with new line code (\n).

How should I change replaceBoldorItalic() or other parts?
Any idea or help??

Comment: But line feed and new line characters are not visible so what's the point?

Comment: I would consider doing this: `var match = new RegExp(text.match(/\n/g), "gm")` like this this `var match = text.match(new RegExp("\\n"),"g")` match should return an array of matches not a RegExp